lighting-input-field does not visualise default values for address compound field
It seems there is a bug where the default value of lightning-input-field for the address compound field is not visualized although the value is properly set. However, default values for other compound fields are visualized and set properly. Simple example:
HTML
<lightning-record-edit-form
            object-api-name='Contact'
            onsubmit={onsubmit}
>
   <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" value={compoundName}></lightning-input-field>
   <lightning-input-field field-name="MailingAddress" value={compoundAddress}></lightning-input-field>

   <lightning-button type="submit" label="Save"></lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>

JS

   compoundName = {
        Salutation: 'Mr.',
        FirstName: 'John',
        LastName: 'Doe',
    }
    
    formattedAddressValue = {
        street: '1234 Trailhead Way',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        postalCode: '94105',
        country: 'USA'
    }

    formattedAddressValueWithinAddressName = {
        MailingStreet: {
            street: '1234 Trailhead Way',
            city: 'San Francisco',
            state: 'CA',
            postalCode: '94105',
            country: 'USA'
        }
    }

    addressElements = {
        MailingStreet: '1234 Trailhead Way',
        MailingCity: 'San Francisco',
        MailingState: 'CA',
        MailingPostalCode: '94105',
        MailingCountry: 'USA'
    }

    addressElementsWithingAddressName = {
        MailingAddress: {
            MailingStreet: '1234 Trailhead Way',
            MailingCity: 'San Francisco',
            MailingState: 'CA',
            MailingPostalCode: '94105',
            MailingCountry: 'USA'
        }
    }

    addressAsText = '1234 Trailhead Way, San Francisco, CA 94105, USA';

    compoundAddress = this.addressElements;
    
    onsubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        // console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.detail.fields)));
    }

The compound Name seems to work, it is displayed and set properly. However, I have tried all of the address value structures from the JS, and the one currently set, addressElemets, seems to work as a default but is not visualized. I know this is the right structure because:

this structure works for the Name compound field
when you do not pass any default values and submit the form with an address, the e.detail.fields contain all address elements and not a compound structure

When you submit the form and debug the e.detail.fields, you can see that the address fields are properly set but not displayed:
//console log info of e.detail.fields
{
    "Salutation": "Mr.",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "MailingStreet": "1234 Trailhead Way",
    "MailingCity": "San Francisco",
    "MailingState": "CA",
    "MailingPostalCode": "94105",
    "MailingCountry": "USA"
}

Am I missing something or is this truly a bug? Also, if it is a bug, I am unsure of where exactly to report it.
